# Problem with CORS, on an Angular and Laravel website

Tags: angular, laravel

In Angular in first step, I uploaded it with the command.

```
ng build --prod --base-href="./"
```

Then unfold the dist folder and put it as the main server path.

Then create the file "proxy.conf.json"

```
"/api-rest-laravel/*":{
  "target": "http://alfarim.es/",
  "secure": false
}
```

Finally modify the file "package.json"

```
        {
  "name": "alfarim-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Then in the Laravel Part -> insert in the project folder "api-rest-laravel", the API part, with the separate public folder. Then modify the file "public / index.php"

```
require __DIR__.'../api-rest-laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'../api-rest-laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then I made sure that the ".env" file also had the data from the database.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</IfModule>


<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

But now the error continues and nothing else is hidden from me.

Please help

Comment: Can you please share your htaccess file?

Comment: You can add allowed origins to your api. <br>
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: The .htaccess is already uploaded